# Was my password copied?

Tags: wordpress, keyloggers, trojan

I work locally with a WordPress site. When I logged in, it looked like the password was highlighted. It went very fast. Half a second maybe. I found it strange that it looked like it was marked, as in the image below.

The reason I am a bit vigilant is that I have a another site with a special login URL that only the owner of the site and I know about, but sometimes there are unknown login attempts there. Could my PC be hijacked? A trojan? How can I find out?

[image: Screenshot of WordPress login with marked password.]

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not a virus. The following xkcd comic illustrates this well:

[image: xkcd/1180]

<sup>CC-BY-NC 2.5: Created by Randall Munroe, [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1180/)</sup>

As you can see, the events you described have nothing to do with a keylogger, a virus, a trojan or what InfoSec professionals generally refer to as "malware". If you really had a malware infection, you would not notice it, and all the security precautions such as "using a secret URL to log in" would be meaningless anyways.

So why was the password marked when you clicked login? God only knows, but malware does not need to "mark" a password to copy it.

As for the invalid login attempts you noticed, this is absolutely normal background noise on the internet.

Comment: Thanks. You say: "If you really had a malware infection, you would not notice it, and all the security precautions such as 'using a secret URL to log in' would be meaningless anyways." And thats the reason why I wonder....

Comment: @fk76 My tip is not to worry about it. If you really need closure, back up your data and re-install your OS.

Comment: The quote you mentioned is said since a malware infected system has so many capabilities to get informations. It can read your browser history, record your internet traffic, install keylogger and more. Having a secret URL is meaningless at that point since it will be a peace of cake for the hacker to find out.
Additionally even if the URL is secret, the thousands of website crawlers out there will find it and that's why you have failed login attempts. As Mech mentioned it's normal internet noise.

Comment: @Nico A crawler can only find a website if it is referenced somewhere in publicly-accessible data.

Comment: I agree with @MechMK1. Finding the right url is quite difficult. I'm not sure that re-installing OS helps in this case. I fear it is at firmware level. Maybe I just forget about it and hope for the best. Maybe its not compromised... but I would have liked to know..

Comment: @fk76 Is there any indicator for a firmware compromise? Or is it a "gut feeling"? Because firmware compromise is something that is very hard to do even for nation state actors.

Comment: @MechMK1 I know, but I assumed that the secret URL for the wordpress admin login is most likely publicly accessible. If it would only be accessible from within a specific network you normally shouldn't see login requests for it.

Comment: @Nico It depends how "secret" the url is. If it's, for example, `example.com/login-bdee3af7-3125-48a5-8818-f65e7a55057a.php`, and it is never referred to anywhere, then it's likely not on google.

Comment: @MechMK1 , A long story in brief ... In 2017, I and an IT technician found strange DNS settings on the computer. And sometimes the screen froze. The IT technician re-installed Windows, but I still thought there was something weird about it. So I decided to use Linux Ubuntu instead. I used Linux for a year, then switched to Windows again. I think it has worked well since then. But sometimes I find some strange things, like the things I wrote about.

Comment: @fk76 I could think of a dozen examples of how any of those things could happen that would be absolutely benign.

Comment: @MechMK1 , ok :)

Comment: @MechMK1,  I can also mention that the reason I am worried is that I had an old computer that behaved strangely. E-mail that did not arrive. Unknown emails in the Draft folder and so on. This had been going on for a long time without my thinking about it. And what I think is that the new computer got infected via USB or something. That's how I think.. But I'm leaving it now..